# Reactjs Static and Dynamic Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am trying to use both Static Routes as well as Dynamic Routes in my React App. I have a JSON File which contains all Dynamic routes the App has which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Text": "Home",
    "Link": "/"
  },
  {
    "Text": "Users",
    "Link": "/Users"
  },
  {
    "Text": "Posts",
    "Link": "/Posts"
  }
]
```

This is my App (i removed some Code, which isn't needed)

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

    return (
        <div className="Grid-Container">
           <Router>
            <Switch>
                <div>
                    <!-- Static Route to the Settings section -->
                    <Route
                        path='/settings/home'
                        component={Settings}
                        key={'Settings'}/>
                    <!-- Dynamic Route which displays all Entries for the chosen Page -->
                    <Route
                        path={`/${page.Text}`}
                        component={objectPage}
                        key={`${page.Text}-List`}
                        exact/>
                    <!-- Dynamic Route which displays one Entry for the chosen Page --> 
                    <Route
                        path={`/:object/:id`}
                        component={DetailPage}
                        key={`Detail-Route`}
                        exact/>
                </div>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The Dynamic Routes are working as expected but as soon as i try to go to the Settings Page, i see the Content of the Detail Page which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the static `Route` as first child of your `Switch`.

What is happening is that the `Switch` is comparing your URL chronologically to your Routes. It interprets your `settings` as a url parameter `:object`. Because it now found  a `Route` that it thinks matches your URL it will render out your Details Page and won't check if any of your other `Routes` match as well or even better.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

    return (
        <div className="Grid-Container">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <!-- Static Route to the Settings section -->
                    <Route
                        path='/settings'
                        component={Settings}
                        key={'Settings'}/>

                    <!-- Dynamic Route which displays all Entries for the chosen Page -->
                    <Route
                        path={`/${page.Text}`}
                        component={<ObjectPage />}
                        key={`${page.Text}-List`}
                        exact/>
                    <!-- Dynamic Route which displays one Entry for the chosen Page -->
                    <Route
                        path={`/:object/:id`}
                        component={DetailPage}
                        key={`Detail-Route`}
                        exact/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have changed the Order as described by you. But now, i have it the other Way around. First, the Settings Component is displayed and under it the Detail Page.

Comment: What do you mean with "under" normally a `<Switch>` only renders the first `<Route>` that satisfies it's `path`. Did you maybe put the `<Route>` outside the `<Switch>`?

Comment: Ehmm, you wrapped all your `Routes` in a `div` in your updated Post. Probably that is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks, that was the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use exact props

```
<Route
       path='/settings'
       component={Settings}
       key={'Settings'}
       exact
/>
```